# Unable to run TestNG due to java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/CommandLineArgs

Tags: java, selenium, intellij-idea, automated-tests, testng

After seting up TestNG in Intellj, I tried to run the Testcase thru the testng.xml file. But I received a -Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/CommandLineArgs- error

none of the other solutions help me. Thanks

I already tried on edit Configuration of Testng changing the suite to the "In whole Project" and "In single Module" options, none of them worked.

The TC already have the @Test() value in order to run them.

TESTNG.XML file configuration

```
    <classes>

        <class name="testCases.TC_1688"/>
        <class name="testCases.TC_1689"/>

    </classes>


</test>
```

I received the following errors

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/testng/CommandLineArgs
    at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main (RemoteTestNGStarter.java:120)

Comment: Please clarify what IDEA version do you use? Do you receive the similar error when the tests are run without IDEA (i.e. with Gradle test)? Sample project to reproduce would be really helpful. Please also check the YouTrack for solutions: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?q=NoClassDefFoundError:%20org%2Ftestng%2FCommandLineArgs

Comment: IDEA 2019.1, I have not tried to run a gradle test. As for the information, I'm just trying to run a login:

Testcases: 
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;// Import package pageObject.*
import appModules.SignIn_Action;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import utility.Constant;

@Test()
public class TC_1688 {

    private static WebDriver driver = null;
….
And trying to run it with the information on the Description of the question

Comment: Sample project with running testng suite works correct for me. Please create an issue at YouTrack providing the sample project and the configuration. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue fixed

remove the old testng-5.11-jdk15 from the Libraries in the Project Structure.ù

Issue was related the following post:
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-143967